# List service in go

Tags: go, kubernetes, knative-serving

I'm trying to list knative (v0.17.0) `services`, I have a `clientset` but I don't know where to start.
Here is a service I launched for my test :

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "helloworld"
spec:
  runLatest:
    configuration:
      revisionTemplate:
        spec:
          container:
            image: "gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go"
            env:
              - name: "TARGET"
                value: "world"
```

If you have any advice, tutorial or example it would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing this off [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mhausenblas/30e8dc5f7682888c10906cb0f8c471cb) adapted for the post-1.18 client-go, and the [Serving `clientset` godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/knative.dev/serving@v0.20.0/pkg/client/clientset/versioned/typed/serving/v1):

```golang
import (
  "context"
  "fmt"
  metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
  "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
  servingv1 "knative.dev/serving/pkg/client/clientset/versioned/typed/serving/v1"
}

func doIt() error {
  config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFLags("", "") // Uses defaults
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  serving, err := servingv1.NewForConfig(config)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  // Get services in the default namespace
  list, err := serving.Services("default").List(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{})
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  // How to print them out.
  fmt.Printf("There are %d services in the default namespace", len(list.Items))
  for _, i := range list.Items {
    fmt.Printf("  > Service %q", i.Name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's clearly the starting point I needed. BTW it's `knative.dev/serving/pkg/` not `knative.dev/servig/pkg/` ;)

Comment: Oh and nothing really related but do you have matrix of every packages related to kubernetes. I struggle a lot to find the right version of each package. Or a tools which could scaffold the `go.mod`

Comment: (Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you)

Comment: In terms of core Kubernetes packages, you should be able to use https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't know how to. Thanks for your answer it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna list knative services then you wanna use the API [here](https://knative.dev/v0.18-docs/reference/api/serving-api/#serving.knative.dev/v1.Service).

For getting you configurations from this yaml, you would set them as **Environment Variables** in env list and then in your code call:

```
os.GetEnv("TARGET")
```

Now using your key from env and the API you can list services.